# MATLAB 2014a (8.3) Compiler Runtime Errors libmwlaunchermain.so

Tags: matlab, ubuntu, matlab-compiler

MATLAB 2014a (8.3) Runtime Compiler (MCR) Errors when trying to launch deployed (using
deploy tool) application in Ubuntu 13.04.

Right after installation of MCR if one runs the deployed application following error appears:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libmwlaunchermain.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.
```

Comment: `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=mcr_root/version/runtime/glnxa64:mcr_root/version/bin/glnxa64:mcr_root/version/sys/os/glnxa64:mcr_root/version/sys/opengl/lib/glnxa64`, [MATLAB Runtime Path Settings for Run-Time Deployment](https://www.mathworks.com/help/compiler/mcr-path-settings-for-run-time-deployment.html).

Answer (score 7):

Since I have already found a solution to this problem wasting a day, I just want to share it:

This seems to be a problem of MATLAB MCR installation script designed for Linux by MathWorks. Furthermore, it is a result of [a known Ubuntu bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xorg/+bug/380360). To fix it, add your MCR to the `$PATH` as shown below:

- First make sure to add the missing files to the right folder, in terminal:

  ```
  sudo cp /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/runtime/glnxa64/* /usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64
  ```
- Add the proper library folder to your `.profile`, such that this change will stay after logout

  ```
  ubuntu: gedit .profile
  ```

  In the end of the file add following lines:

  ```
  #MATLAB MCR

  export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/bin/glnxa64
  export XAPPLRESDIR=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/X11/app-defaults

  export PATH=$PATH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
  export PATH=$PATH:$XAPPLRESDIR
  ```
- Invoke following code in the terminal to make sure that Ubuntu bug doesn't re-write your variable:

  ```
  echo STARTUP=\"/usr/bin/env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=\${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} \${STARTUP}\" | sudo tee /etc/X11/Xsession.d/90preserve_ld_library_path
  ```
- Reboot

If this solution doesn't work, try to reinstall MATLAB MCR 8.3 from the MathWorks website and repeat the steps.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Matlab R2016b = v91), the binary generated by Matlab was accompanied by a shell script which sets up the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` for me. If I just run

```
./run_scriptname.sh
```

it complains about the missing `<deployedMCRroot>`. So running the script with

```
./run_scriptname.sh /home/user/MatlabMCR/v91
```

it worked out of the box.

For me, it was not obvious that the path shown above is the `<deployedMCRroot>` because I chose `/home/user/MatlabMCR` as installation directory. And with the wrong path specified, it led to the same error message.