# How do I install the Matlab MCR in Ubuntu 14.04 without "killing" Unity?

Tags: matlab, shared-libraries, ubuntu-14.04, matlab-deployment

Background: I have created an Ubuntu [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/%20VirtualBox) from [LAPP stack](https://bitnami.com/stack/lapp) and added the Ubuntu desktop (Unity: `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`). Now I am attempting to install the MCR without loosing Unity.

- [Download](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/compiler/mcr/) MCR zip and extract to MCR_SOURCE
- Go to my folder that contains the files: `cd /media/sf_shared/MCR_ SOURCE`
- Change `installer_input.txt` file:

  ```
  destinationFolder=/opt/MCR
  agreeToLicense=yes
  outputFile=/opt/install.log
  mode=silent
  product.MATLAB
  product.MATLAB_Builder_JA
  # Note: To find out the required toolboxes >> start Matlab >> run your code and find out which toolboxes were used with: license('inuse')
  ```
- Install MCR: `sudo ./install -inputFile /media/sf_shared/MCR_SOURCE/installer_input.txt` >> success
- Restart Ubuntu >> test whether Ubuntu’s Unity still exists >> everything is fine
- Attention  the next step will “ *kill* ” your Ubuntu desktop configuration!!! (i.e. copy your hardisk, anything you must do to recover quickly) – now configure: `sudo gedit /etc/environment`

  ```
  LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/MCR/v84/runtime/glnxa64:/opt/MCR/v84/bin/glnxa64:/opt/MCR/v84/sys/os/glnxa64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
  XAPPLRESDIR="/opt/MCR/v84/X11/app-defaults"
  # Note: X11/app-defaults folder has not been created during installation
  ```
- Restart Ubuntu >> Unity is gone, recovery attempts such as deleting the above lines do not recover Unity; reinstalling the Ubuntu desktop does not help either.

I have tried an [alternative route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004240/matlab-2014a-8-3-compiler-runtime-errors-libmwlaunchermain-so) with exporting the variables, which also "kills" Unity. By the way this affects all users.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

It is not necessary to register these environment variables in `/etc/environment`, which means that the Unity sidebar will not be affected.

Instead register the environment variables temporarily either as local user or via `sudo -i`:

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/opt/MCR/v84/runtime/glnxa64:/opt/MCR/v84/bin/glnxa64:/opt/MCR/v84/sys/os/glnxa64:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
export XAPPLRESDIR="/opt/MCR/v84/X11/app-defaults"
```

Now it is possible to run Matlab Apps without "killing" Ubuntu's desktop. For instance to run the Java compiled `makesqr.m` file.

```
java -classpath "/opt/MCR/v84/toolbox/javabuilder/jar/javabuilder.jar:/media/sf_shared/for_testing/makesqr.jar" makesqr.Class1 5
```

The Java package `makesqr` was created using [Matlab's JavaBuilder tutorial](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/javabuilder/ug/create-a-java-class-from-matlab-code.html). This was done on my Windows 7 machine, which runs Matlab R2014b.

Please ensure that the owner and permissions of the `/opt/MCR` and `/media/sf_shared/for_testing` folders are set correctly (see [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/224794-how-do-i-overcome-the-java-mcr-proxy-library-initialisation-error-in-ubuntu) for details).