# Error loading shared libraries in Matlab Runtime application running Fmask 4.0

Tags: matlab, ubuntu-14.04, matlab-compiler

Hi I have installed FMask 4.0; a software that utilises MatLab Runtime (v93) onto Linux Ubuntu 14.04.

https://github.com/GERSL/Fmask

However, after installation, I can't run the application. When calling the software from the command line, the following is returned:

```
/home/wr/Fmask/application/Fmask_4_0: error while loading shared libraries: libmwlaunchermain.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

This appears to have been a common issue in the past and was answered in a previous question:

[MATLAB 2014a (8.3) Compiler Runtime Errors libmwlaunchermain.so](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24004240/matlab-2014a-8-3-compiler-runtime-errors-libmwlaunchermain-so)

I have followed the instructions but this hasn't solved the problem, hence why I'm opening a new thread.

Comment: I just fixed a typo in one of the commands on the linked answer (missing space). Also, those commands need to be adjusted to your local configuration. So, please, let us know exactly what you tried to do (and if you understand the concepts behind the solution that the linked answer proposes).

Comment: Thanks Cris, yes I understand I need to adjust the folder paths for my local configuration. However, my Matlab Compiler version doesn't contain an X11 folder so I'm unable to input a folder path for this in my .profile file XAPPLRESDIR=/usr/local/MATLAB/MATLAB_Compiler_Runtime/v83/X11/app-defaults

Comment: Hum, yes, things change from one version of MATLAB to the next... Also your version of Ubuntu is different, I don't know if the mentioned bug is also in yours.

Comment: Yes, the version of MATLAB I have was installed as part of the installation process. I will try an older version perhaps and see if it still works.